# MapInfo Thematic mapping - line width based on a field

Tags: mapinfo, line, thematic-map

I want to apply thematic mapping to a layer in MapInfo with varying line thicknesses based on a float column. Is this possible?

Answer (score 4):

Yes it is.

When creating the thematic map, pick Ranges and then pick the template called "Line Ranges, different widths".

It might not have this exact name as that's translated from my Danish MI Pro to English.